# Errors in my generic class when trying to pass an interface in the constructor

Tags: c#, generics, interface

Here I have 2 methods out of 15+ that calls a SOAP web service

```
       public async void CallWebServiceA() {
            var client = new WebServiceWRGClient();
            var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;
            binding.MaxBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
            var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("https://trustonline.delawarecpf.com/tows/webservicewrg.svc"); 
            var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<WebServiceWRG>(binding, endpoint);
            var webService = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
            var user = new GRACE_GRACES.User();
            user.UserName = await webService.EncryptValueAsync("username");
            user.Password = await webService.EncryptValueAsync("password12345");
            var response = await client.ClaimSearchAsync(user, "", "", 12345, GRACE_GRACES.statuscode.NotSet, "");
       }

       public async void CallWebServiceB() {
            var client = new WebServiceAWIClient();
            var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;
            binding.MaxBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
            var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("https://trustonline.delawarecpf.com/tows/webserviceawi.svc"); 
            var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<WebServiceAWI>(binding, endpoint);
            var webService = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
            var user = new ARM_ARMS.User();
            user.UserName = await webService.EncryptValueAsync("username");
            user.Password = await webService.EncryptValueAsync("password12345");
            var response = await client.ClaimSearchAsync(user, "", "", 12345, ARM_ARMS.statuscode.NotSet, "");
       }
```

I have this generic class below that I created so I don't have to make multiple redudant methods for each of my 15+ urls/web services all from the same provider, but I have some errors with passing in the 2nd parameter, which is an interface (from the web service reference).

```
public class WebService<T1, T2, T3> {
    private T1 _client;
    private T2 _interface;
    private T3 _user;

    public WebService(T1 wsClient, T2 wsInterface, T3 wsUser) {
        _client = wsClient;
        _interface = wsInterface;
        _user = wsUser;
    }

    public void CallWebService(string url, string userName, string password) {
        var client = _client; 
        var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
        var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(url); 
        var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<_interface>(binding, endpoint);  
        var webService = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
        var user = _user;
        user.UserName = webService.EncryptValue(userName);
        user.Password = webService.EncryptValue(password);
        var response = client.ClaimSearch(user, "", "", 12345, GraceStatuscode.NotSet, "");
    }

}
```

I'm calling it like this below but the interfaces WebServiceWRG and WebServiceAWI aren't recognized in the parameters when I create the instance or in the method when I create a new instance of ChannelFactory. I get a red line saying "the type of namespace name _interface could not be found" and in the line where I create the new class instance I get a red line for each interface parameter saying "'WebServiceWRG' is a type, which is not valid in the given context"

```
WebService someServiceA = new WebService(new WebServiceWRGClient(), WebServiceWRG, new GRACE_GRACES.User());
WebService someServiceB = new WebService(new WebServiceAWIClient(), WebServiceAWI, new ARM_ARMS.User());
```

**UPDATED**
Here is what I've tried below but still have errors: 
user.UserName = webService.EncryptValue(userName); //TTwo does not contain a def for 'UserName', T does not contain a def for EncryptValue

```
   public class Test {
        public void TestWebService() {
            var ws = new WebService<WebServiceWRG>();
            ws.SearchClaim(new WebServiceWRGClient(), new GraceUser(), "url", "userName", "password");
        }
    }

    public class WebService<T> { 
        public void SearchClaim<TOne, TTwo>(TOne entity1, TTwo entity2, string url, string userName, string password) 
            where TOne : class
            where TTwo : class
        {
            var client = entity1;
            var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
            var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(url);
            var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<T>(binding, endpoint);
            var webService = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
            var user = entity2;
            user.UserName = webService.EncryptValue(userName); // username not found, encryptvalue not found
            user.Password = webService.EncryptValue(password); // passwordnot found, encryptvalue not found
            var response = client.ClaimSearch(user, "", "", 12345, GraceStatuscode.NotSet, ""); // claimsearch not found
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not the issue with Generics but it is the issue the way you are calling the constructor of `WebService`. The constructor of `WebService` expects three parameters. You are passing first and third parameter values with object created by `new` keyword. And second parameter you want to pass just as interface name. That's how it doesn't work. You need to pass an object of class which implements interface `WebServiceWRG` and/or `WebServiceWRG`.

Comment: The syntax being used is not correct. The question in its current state is also incomplete and therefore unclear. This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: @user1186050 There are many syntax issues with this code but without guidance from you about what it is you are actually trying to do, there is not much help that can be provided.

Comment: I'm sending data to an online service/web service (I updated the code at the top of my post) to show the method. But I have roughly 15 different urls and each url/web service has it's own references that were generated by .net. So each time I call "ClaimSearch()" from the web service I have to construct the parameters with a different client, interface, user. Where each one of these is coming from the different service references.

Comment: @user1186050 - please decide on what you want to ask here - syntax of creating instance of generic type (for some reason you pass variable rather than type), syntax of passing parameters to methods (there is no valid case where you pass class name as parameter of any method in C#) or something else (note that first two options has plenty of coverage on SO already). So far question simply looks like "simple typographical error"...

Comment: In my method at the top of the post WebServiceWRGClient(), WebServiceWRG and GRACE_GRACES.User() are all hard coded instances referring to a specific reference/namespace. I want a generic method where these 3 values can be generic so I don't have to create 15+ more methods like the one at the top to each and every other web service I have to call.

Answer (score 1):

*Let's first acknowledge that the changes you're making are the right kind of changes. Working to avoid code duplication is important and can improve code quality significantly. Well done!*

This could be a step in the right direction:

```
public class WebService<T1, T2, T3> {
    private T1 _client;
    private T3 _user;

    //No T2

    public WebService(T1 wsClient, T3 wsUser) {
        _client = wsClient;
        _user = wsUser;
        //No interface
    }

    public void CallWebService(string url, string userName, string password) {
        (...)
        var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<T2>(binding, endpoint);   <---- use the T2 type
        (...)
    }
}
```

and then

```
var someServiceA = new WebService<WebServiceWRGClient, WebServiceWRG, Whatever_GRACE_GRACES_User()_returns_here>(new WebServiceWRGClient(), new GRACE_GRACES.User());
```

*(Please note the var because the type is not `WebService` but `WebService<X,Y,Z>`)*

---

## Next step

I don't think you need generics for the client and the user, and the next step could be:

```
public class WebService<T> {
    private Baseclassofallclients _client;
    private UserTypeHere _user;


    public WebService( Baseclassofallclients wsClient, UserTypeHere  wsUser) {
        _client = wsClient;
        _user = wsUser;
        //No interface
    }

    public void CallWebService(string url, string userName, string password) {
        (...)
        var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<T>(binding, endpoint);   <---- use the T type here
        (...)
    }
```

and then

```
var someServiceA = new WebService<WebServiceWRG>(new WebServiceWRGClient(), new GRACE_GRACES.User());
var someServiceB = new WebService<WebServiceAWI>(new WebServiceAWIClient(), new ARM_ARMS.User());
```

Comment: hi Tymtam. I don't think I understand your usage of 'UserTypeHere', could you please explain wihat this is and how it would work with an example?

Comment: Tymtam, each of my Users() are coming from each of the different web service references.

Comment: I tried your first example and it doesn't work because the class still expects 3 arguments and now your only passing 2

Comment: What class `.User()` return for GRACE and ARM?

Comment: Hi Tymtam. The User() class that gets returned is a partial class from the namespace that's created from each specific webservice. So I reference the namespace like this: using GRACE_GRACES; and then create an alias like this: using GraceUser = GRACE_GRACES.User; then I'll use it like this: var user = new GRACE_GRACES.User();

Comment: so I think that inside the generic class "WebService" I should have a generic user?

Comment: What is the type that `ClaimSearchAsync` takes as the first parameter?

Comment: It takes a user, which comes from the specific web service. So each one is different that gets passed in as an argument is from a different namespace. I'm going to add more code in my post to show what I have so far, but I still have errors. I'll comment it accordingly.

Comment: "It takes a user," <--- what class is this user? Is it `User`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200036/discussion-between-tymtam-and-user1186050).